# Return assigned scopes when introspecting an access token?

Tags: curity

Note: I'm using Curity Identity Server community edition.

In attempting to create an OAuth mechanism, I'm trying to use 'scopes' as a mechanism to report what scopes a given client/secret pair has access to if a requested scope is not provided.

Then, when using the introspection endpoint from the API, I'd be able to determine if the bearer token and its corresponding client have access to a given API endpoint *based on those scopes*, rather than having to have the client making the request have to define the scope before they get the token.

In a customized introspection script, how would I get a list of all scopes that this client ID has available to it and return that as an attribute in the returned JSON data when hitting the introspection endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

When you create a token procedure for the introspection flow, you have access to the client and its configured scopes via the `context` variable.
Add the following line to the script to return the configured scopes in the introspection response:

`responseData.configured_scoped = context.getClient().scopeNames;`

See also https://curity.io/docs/idsvr/latest/developer-guide/scripting/token-procedure-api.html#utilities

Comment: Derp glanced right over that in the docs.  Thanks for the help, let me test this and get back to you :)

Comment: I did a test and this worked perfectly for my needs, thank you!

Comment: I'm going to have to unaccept this, because while it worked in testing, it did NOT work in production.  It returns an empty set, which makes me wonder if this is a Curity bug or such.  The requests are coming in without scopes, so on introspection it should return the scopes that *are* set on there.  Which is... unusual... that it won't return all valid scopes for a given client and instead returns an empty set.  Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: Because I couldn't find anything in the API that could do this with the 'default scope', I simply said "screw it" and will design around scope-based requests to make sure a specific scope is able to be retrieved or not for access validation or not.  Which is probably more in line of how scopes work anyways, for OAuth2 spec and behavior.  So, ultimately, I abandoned this 'list all scopes available to a user' approach.